# if the hide() jquery animate function set after animate(),it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, jquery-animate

First I have a animate a iframe which id is "test"

```
<iframe id="test" src=""></iframe>
```

then I want animate it and hide it ,make a close effect like in MacOS:

```
$('#test').animate({
                'width':0,
                'height':0,
                'top':$('input').offset().top,
                'left':$('input').offset().left
            },function(){
                //$(this).hide();        
            }).hide();
```

but it seems the iframe can not be hide.However,if I write it in the callback function that in animate,which is the annotated code above.It could work again.

[Here is online case](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/UEQ9q/)

So I wonder why the hide() after animate() doesn't work?Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question, the call to `.hide()` is performed *immediately* after the call to `.animate()`, so the `.hide()` invocation actually takes place *before* the animation completes, (`.animate()` runs asynchronously) - this is why jQuery provides the callback function to you so you can be notified of when the animation completes.

```
$('#test').animate({
            'width':0,
            'height':0,
            'top':$('input').offset().top,
            'left':$('input').offset().left
        }, function(){
             $("#test").hide();
        });
```

**Saved this for you on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UEQ9q/3/) too**

Comment: Thank you.But now the problem is not about duration,or "correct Dom element".In my code above ,if I write  "……},function(){$(this).hide();}"directly,it could also work .The problem is the  why "animate().hide()" doesn't work?

Comment: @hh54188 I edited my answer long ago. Please take a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: @hh54188 because of asynchronous execution?

Comment: @ Jacob Relkin:Sorry,I just notice that you have edited it .Thank you very much.I haven't notice that there exists an asynchronous execution process before.I have got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `opacity` to `hide` and it will work:

```
$('#mask').click(function () {            
    $('#mask').fadeOut(500);
    $('#test').animate({
        opacity: 'hide',
        'top':$('input').offset().top,
        'left':$('input').offset().left,
    },3000);

});
```

Comment: @Saturo.Logic, this is nice, but it actually doesn't hide the `iframe` completely because it's `display` CSS property is still `block`.

Comment: @Jacob Is it the difference between `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`?

Comment: @Saturo.Logic Yes, there is a difference.